# Stabilize metal legs attached to wood table top

Tags: table

I have a table top constructed of pine planks on plywood.  It is about 1" thick, 3'x5' dimensions.  I then have two X-frame table legs constructed from 2"x2" square steel tubing with a 4" flat plate on top to attach to the table top. Any ideas for added stability to prevent movement side to side?  I would like to avoid solutions that require additional welding.  Thanks!

Comment: Diagonal braces of virtually any sort would do. The key is to match aesthetics to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, attaching the X-frame legs so that the back plates are closer together than the front plates will allow the front legs to act as stabilizers vs sideward movement.  This solution assumes that the plates are not rocking; that the screws threads are gripping tightly and the screw heads don't permit any rocking of the plate, either (ie. use of washers keep plate firmly against underside of table).

Answer (score 0):

You could take 2 pieces of flat stock steel, perhaps 1/8" x 1.5" and bend both ends to 45°.  Drill holes in the bent ends.  Paint the metal to match the legs.  Use wood screws to attach to the table bottom and self drilling sheet metal screws on the metal legs.  [image]